# Initialising Java String literal giving error

Tags: java, optional-parameters

This java string literal initializing giving error when the code to initialize is within checking if par1 has a value or not. I am not sure whether I am doing or its some other issue??

[image]

```
public class optionalFields {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        optional_func(Optional.of(true));
    }

        public static void optional_func(Optional<Boolean> par1)
    {
        if(par1.isPresent())
            String s = "test";
        System.out.println(s);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Declaration is not allowed in a simple if (without a block)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be:

```
if (par1.isPresent()) {
    String s = "test";
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

You cannot declare a variable inside an `if` statement unless you put the declaration in a block. Besides, since you are printing `s`, the `println` statement should also be inside the block of the `if` statement.

If you want to print `s` even if the condition is false, it should be:

```
String s = null;
if (par1.isPresent())
    s = "test";
System.out.println(s);
```